# Shortcut for 'Find related messages' in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Is it possible in Outlook 2010 to bind a keyboard shortcut to the "Find Related -> Messages in this conversation" functionality?

I tried the "Customize Ribbon" and "Customize Quick Access Toolbar" options to get a button that could be bound to an Alt-key combination, but I am unable to find the "Find Related" command, or the "Messages in this conversation" command in the list of available commands.

If anyone has resolved such an issue, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I realize this isn't for Outlook 2010, but this may provide you with enough inspiration on how to build based upon the Outlook 2007 structure.*

**Note:** The following example could be built using a VBA Macro or Outlook Plugin.

If you locate where "Related Messages" exists in the `CommandBar` hierarchy (*Outlook Menu structure*) - you can leverage the `Copy` mechanism and place the existing `CommandBarButton` in the Standard `CommandBar` (*in the case of Outlook 2007*). Once you've done this - you can rename the `Caption` and assign a different shortcut key (*see below for reference*). In this example, we can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to trigger the "Related Messages" advanced find dialog.

#### VSTO Reference

```
Outlook.Explorer explorer = Application.ActiveExplorer();

// retrieve menu toolbar for this explorer
CommandBar menuBar = explorer.CommandBars.ActiveMenuBar;

for (int i = 1; i <= menuBar.Controls.Count; i++)
{
    if (menuBar.Controls[i].Caption == "&Tools")
    {
        var toolsMenu = menuBar.Controls[i] as CommandBarPopup;
        for (int j = 1; j <= toolsMenu.Controls.Count; j++)
        {
            if (toolsMenu.Controls[j].Caption == "&Instant Search")
            {
                var searchMenu = toolsMenu.Controls[j] as CommandBarPopup;

                for (int k = 1; k <= searchMenu.Controls.Count; k++)
                {
                    if (searchMenu.Controls[k].Caption == "&Related Messages...")
                    {
                        var related = searchMenu.Controls[k] as CommandBarButton;
                        var relatedClone = related.Copy(explorer.CommandBars["Standard"]);
                        relatedClone.Caption = "Related &Messages";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

}

In Outlook 2010, you may just try doing the following since there isn't a standard commandbar (*it was replaced by the ribbon UI*). The usage would then be <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to trigger the "Related Messages" advanced find dialog. However - this hasn't been tested though.

```
var relatedClone = related.Copy(menuBar);
```

#### VBA Reference

```vb
Sub AddRelatedMessages()
   Dim menuBar As CommandBar
   Dim toolsMenu As CommandBarPopup, searchMenu As CommandBarPopup
   Dim related As CommandBarButton, relatedClone As CommandBarButton
   Set menuBar = Application.ActiveExplorer().CommandBars.ActiveMenuBar

   Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

   For i = 1 To menuBar.Controls.Count Step 1
        If (menuBar.Controls(i).Caption = "&Tools") Then
            Set toolsMenu = menuBar.Controls(i)
            For j = 1 To toolsMenu.Controls.Count Step 1
                If (toolsMenu.Controls(j).Caption = "&Instant Search") Then
                    Set searchMenu = toolsMenu.Controls(j)
                    For k = 1 To searchMenu.Controls.Count Step 1
                        If (toolsMenu.Controls(k).Caption = "&Related Messages...") Then
                            Set related = searchMenu.Controls(k)
                            Set relatedClone = related.Copy(Explorer.CommandBars("Standard"))
                            relatedClone.Caption = "Related &Messages"
                        End If
                    Next k
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think 'Related Messages' reside inside Instant Search. I added Instant Search to Quick Access Toolbar but can't see any drill-down options.

Comment: 'Related Messages' resides in Instant Search for Outlook 2007. Unfortunately, I don't have Outlook 2010 to see where it lives.

Comment: Yes you are right. It used to be in Outlook 2007, but in 2010 it has been rearranged and now I am not able to find it :(.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> then (<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>).

But it is not working with me as when I do (<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) it goes to file tap.

Comment: How does this answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

to get a button that could be bound to an Alt-key combination,

- go to "Customize the Ribbon", "All Commands"
- scroll to "Find Messages in Conversation"
- add (Add >>) it to Home, New Group (Custom)

After that right-click the new button "Messages in this Conversation" which is now on the Home ribbon and select

- add to quick toolbar

In my case is the fourth quick toolbar button so ALT-4 is the shortcut.

Hope this answer your question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).